# What are potential downsides of using single constant hash key in DynamoDB?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

What problems might arise if all records in the table have the same hash key value and different sort key values?

It feels to me that this should work OK, because the throughput will be “uniformly distributed” and all the allocated throughput will be assigned to this single hash key (or rather to the partition it is in). However, it seems a bit unusual for DynamoDB design and I wonder if there is anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably run into Hot Partition problems.

The capacity assigned to a table is normally spread across partitions. If all data is stored in one partition, you will not have access to the full capacity of the table.

See:

- [Partitions and Data Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html)
- [Design For Uniform Data Access Across Items In Your Tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload)

Comment: I don't think that is true. If there is only one hash key that means that there is only one partition, isn't it? So that hash key will have full table capacity

Comment: Slight correction to my previous comment: It does not mean that there is only 1 partition, as that depends on the data size and throughput (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions). However, it still means that all throughput is allocated to the same hash key